# Why when i hover over my text box it doesnt affect the background

Tags: html, css

if you hover over one of my posts on this site http://motivationalblogging.com/ it zooms. I got the zoom to work, but as soon as i hover over the text that appears the zoom stops. I have tried every different way i can think to keep the background zooming but cannot figure out why.

Thankyou

Comment: Whatever event listener you are using to tell the image to zoom, instead of adding the event to the image, add it to the parent of the image (the container of each image and all the text regarding it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a:link {
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
color: gray;
}

a:hover {
  color: pink;
}

a:active {
  color: yellow;
}

.background-switch {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  max-width: 250px;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.background-switch:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;

}

.hover-rotate { margin-left: 30px; }

.hover-rotate:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);

}

.hover-outline { 
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.hover-outline:hover {
  outline: 5px solid gray;
  outline-offset: 10px;
}
```

---

```
<h1><a href="http://www.fakesite.doesnt-exist.com-tk"> </a></h1>
<p class="background-switch">Ok, now that you've done that, hover me next!</p>
```